# Searching through a list of items, using a searchbar component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, search, filter

I have a list of items on display, and am trying to filter out certain results or show them based on tickboxes. The search function is in another component, and I am passing the array of items to it, as well as the method to update the parent's state so objects change, and a reload function to reset the system.

I am having issues with the timing of the props coming in though, as the child state array returns empty if set in componentDid/WillMount. I can set the state in the onChange methods, but this leads to the state being reset each time a box is ticked. When should I be setting the child state, then what would be the best way to update it each time a box is ticked?

Child component call in parent:

```
<ManagePostsSearchBar parentResults={filteredPosts} 
           results={this.fetchSearchData} filteredPostsUpdated={this.filteredPostsUpdated} 
           />
```

Child component handleChange method

```
// Checkboxes should change what is displayed each tick, by filtering the array
        handleCheckBox=(e)=>{
        this.setState ({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        }); 
        if (!e.target.checked) {
            this.setState({[e.target.id]: ''
        });
        // Not sure where this goes, as it won't update quickly enough in componentDid/WillMount,
        //  only seems to work here
        this.setState({
            parentResults: this.props.parentResults
        });
        // trying to create a new array with search results
        var filterArray = this.state.parentResults.filter(
            result => result.viewable===this.state.hidden
        )
        }
        console.log(this.state);
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated, think it comes down to an understanding of lifecycles, but also struggling to get my logic right for the filter function so might need a hand with that too! 
Thanks!

view of what the page looks like

Comment: don't try to set the state with values from props unless there is a valid usecase like the values are updated

Comment: Array.filter returns a new array and it doesn't update the state unless required. So, the console.log will not work in this case

Comment: Okay, I'm using vars now, but struggling with the filter function, as it's returning undefined.
```
var parentArray = this.props.parentResults;
        

        var {filterArray} = parentArray.filter(
            result => result.viewable===this.state.hidden
        )
        console.log(filterArray);
```

Comment: I am not sure about that. Please check what data comes from parent and from state.hidden. It would be great if there's a working codepen example or so. It'll be easy to debug

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, it is the same idea: https://codepen.io/mtclmn/pen/QyPVJp

```
  var FilteredList = React.createClass({
  filterList: function(event){
    var updatedList = this.state.initialItems;
    updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(item){
      return item.toLowerCase().search(
        event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    this.setState({items: updatedList});
  },
  getInitialState: function(){
     return {
       initialItems: [
         "Apples",
         "Broccoli",
         "Chicken",
         "Duck",
         "Eggs",
         "Fish",
         "Granola",
         "Hash Browns"
       ],
       items: []
     }
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.setState({items: this.state.initialItems})
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="filter-list">
        <form>
        <fieldset className="form-group">
        <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.filterList}/>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
      <List items={this.state.items}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var List = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <ul className="list-group">
      {
        this.props.items.map(function(item) {
          return <li className="list-group-item" data-category={item} key={item}>{item}</li>
        })
       }
      </ul>
    )  
  }
});

React.render(<FilteredList/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: I've tried the following based on your code:
   ` filterArray = filterArray.filter(function (result) {
            return result.viewable===e.target.value
        })
        console.log(filterArray); `
But it's returning an empty array, any ideas?

Comment: can you confirm that the result.viewable is of same type as target value? That would be of big impact in this case